# Pandas: Is better aggregation possible

Tags: python, pandas

```
Ddate   Test Name   T/F
01-01-2019  Haem    T
02-01-2019  Haem    T
03-01-2019  Haem    T
04-01-2019  Haem    F
05-01-2019  Haem    F
01-01-2019  CBC T
02-01-2019  CBC T
03-01-2019  CBC T
04-01-2019  CBC F
05-01-2019  CBC F
01-01-2019  KFT T
02-01-2019  KFT T
03-01-2019  KFT T
04-01-2019  KFT F
05-01-2019  KFT F
```

I have sample dataframe above. I wish to calculate percentage True for each date. I am able to do as below. But, feel it can be done with groupby + agg. Is it possible?

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['T/F'] = df['T/F'].map({'T':1, 'F':0})
df['T'] = np.where(df['T/F']==1, 1, 0)
df['F'] = 1 - df['T']

df = df.groupby('Ddate').agg(
    {
        'T': sum,
        'F': sum,
    }
)

df['Total'] = df['T'] + df['F']
df['per T'] = df['T'] / df['Total'] * 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do groupby like this:

```
df['T/F'].eq('T').groupby([df['Date']]).mean()
```

Output:

```
Date
01-01-2019    1.0
02-01-2019    1.0
03-01-2019    1.0
04-01-2019    0.0
05-01-2019    0.0
Name: T/F, dtype: float64
```

You can get both percentages for `T` and `F` with `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.Date, df['T/F'], normalize='index')
```

Output:

```
T/F           F    T
Date                
01-01-2019  0.0  1.0
02-01-2019  0.0  1.0
03-01-2019  0.0  1.0
04-01-2019  1.0  0.0
05-01-2019  1.0  0.0
```

**Note 1**: Extra comment to your code: The counts per date can be obtained by:

```
counts = pd.crosstab(df['Date'], df['T/F'])
```

Then the percentage of `T` can be:

```
counts['per T'] = counts['T']/counts.sum(axis=1)
```

**Note 2**: Don't do `groupby().agg({'col1': sum, 'col2':sum})` because:

1. `sum` is python native, and is slow
2. `agg` is slow(er), and only useful when you want to perform different operations to different columns.

Do: `groupby()[['col1','col2']].sum()`

**Note 3**: All of the solutions above give percentage in scale `0-1`. If you want scale `0-100`, you know what to do.

Comment: Doesn't give the same output

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want the count? Or do you just want the percentage? The percentage should definitely be the same with your output.

Comment: @Anant you didn't provide the output ;)